# Awaiting the removal of an item from an object model

Tags: javascript, redux, async-await, jestjs, react-testing-library

In my React project, I've built several Action Creators, which manipulate the connected object model in Redux.

When building tests for these, I've been entirely successful when adding an item to the object model, like this:

```
store = configureStore(initialPopulatedState);
await store.dispatch(actions.addTask());
await wait(() => store.getState().formBuilder.serviceForm.steps[2].tasks);
```

But now I'm wanting to test the removal of something.  This isn't working correctly:

```
store = configureStore(initialPopulatedState);
expect(state.serviceForm.steps[0].tasks).toHaveLength(3);
await store.dispatch(actions.removeTask('b80d8081-6c32-4d62-b0f1-64cdd28d4b88'));
// await wait(() => store.getState().formBuilder.serviceForm.steps[0].tasks.length === 2);
// await wait(() => expect(store.getState().formBuilder.serviceForm.steps[0].tasks).toHaveLength(2));
```

Neither of those `await` statements work but I think some variation of this syntax should.
If you have any ideas, please let me know!  Thanks.

Comment: What are the contents/properties of `removeTask` and `addTask`? Are they dumb actions? Do they have async calls in them (a thunk or maybe generator?)

Comment: Dominik, each calls one or more actions, which in turn call reducers which alter the object model in Redux.  To reiterate, the tests for `addTask` work perfectly.  The `await wait(() => ...)` statement I showed above works because it waits until `tasks` changes from an empty array to an array with an element in it.  I'm trying to figure out how to monitor for the reverse of this.

Comment: @robertwerner_sf If `removeTask` is a thunk then you should **return** a promise: `const removeTask = (arg) => (dispatch,getState)=>return something.then.then.then....`